# The “Shimmer” effect in Keynote uses white sparkles. How can I change them to red sparkles?

Tags: macos, keynote, color, animation

I would like to modify one of the keynote standard animations to have the white sparkles be red.   I'd like to have the white animation below to be red in color.

[image: Animation showing white sparkles]

My setup is currently Keynote 13.1 (7037.0.101) on  macOS Venture 13.4.1 (c)

**Is there a color palette I can modify to achieve this?**

Comment: Can you place a very small red circle or text period over the image and sparkle that?

Answer (score 0):

This effect's colour will change according to the colour of the text, image or shape to which it is applied.

To have it red, you have to make your text red.

[image: gif with three different text colours and therefore with three different shimmer colours]

Comment: I can't attach my screen shots but you can see the white sparkles at time position 01:40:22 in [the end product](https://youtu.be/lSxcJEbipSE). I selected the star object that now sparkles white, with fill and border set to None to make it transparent. I then selected Format > Text > Text Color and set it to Red, but the sparkles remained white. I then set Format > Text > Image Fill to a different color but it still didn't change the sparkle color. Keynote and MacOS versions are noted above.

Comment: @DaveSieving This works with the colour of the shape (in this case). You could try to have a red shape shimmer as a built-in animation and then disappear (opacity to 0%) as an action animation. Make sure you set duration to 0s. That's the best thing I could find in your case, I'll see if I can find something else. :)